# pm2 start mongod throws of errored after few seconds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, amazon-ec2

Have node server to a server application which is deployed on amazon ec2 instance with OS Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version, node- 12.18.3, mongoDB - 4.2.8, npm- 6.14.6 & pm2- 4.4.0.

The command `service mongod status` returns active(running status) now when `pm2 status mongod` command is executed it starts and both show online status running but when `pm2 status` command is executed node shows online status whereas mongod shows errored.

Have tried to make `mongod --repair` but still the problem persist.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to run mongo with pm2?

Comment: My bad it was status not start.